# "Error: Multiple apps in git remotes" after web dyno crash on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm setting a staging environment following the steps [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments).

```
heroku create --remote staging
```

I checked on the site and a new app was created. Then I attempted to push a specific branch to it:

```
git push --remote staging  my_branch:master
```

A build was created and I got a message that it's deployed to the app's URL. But when I went there it displayed an `Application Error`. The logs report this issue:

```
Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
  Usage: --remote staging
  or: --app <app_name>
  Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
  Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
  Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
  Heroku remotes in repo:
  <original_app_name> (heroku)
  <new_app_name> (staging)
```

I tried various combinations of using `--remote app_name` or `--app app_name` but I'm getting an `unknown option` error like this:

```
error: unknown option `remote'
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing `git` command arguments with `heroku` ones. [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) has no `--remote` argument; to deploy, just give the remote name on the command-line:

```
git push staging my_branch:master
```

I think you actually did that properly since you saw a deploy happen.

Now, the error message you're seeing isn't the application error. It's an error from the `heroku` CLI [`logs` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs) telling you that it doesn't know whether it should show logs for your production application or your staging one.

Try

```
heroku logs --remote staging
```

or

```
heroku logs --app <new_app_name>
```

to see the actual server-side logs that should contain details about your application crash.